# How to view iPhone music history?

Tags: iphone, music.app

Is there a way to see the history of played tracks directly on the iPhone? I didn't find an option to do that in the Music app.

Comment: well i guess this is kinda redundant now it has upnext

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't see this on an iOS device. If you create a smart playlist like this, you can look in iTunes, after syncing your iPhone, to see what you've listened to.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a feature that's ever been directly included as a human readable list in iTunes, on an iPod, or any modern generation iOS device.

This information is stored in a machine readable format, which is used first for a song's play counts (viewable only in iTunes), but there is also software written to take advantage of this information, and send it to a 'listening history' service like [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm/).

I've used a lot of scrobbling apps on iOS. Many have worked over time, but if you use iTunes Match, I highly suggest using [CloudScrob](http://cloudscrob.com/). If you don't, there are a myriad of other apps in the iTunes App Store, you can find them by searching for 'Scrobble', 'Scrobbler', or 'Last.fm'.

**Note** that the official [Last.fm iOS app](http://www.last.fm/group/Last.fm+for+iPhone+and+iPod+Touch) ([iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/last.fm/id284916679?mt=8)) ***DOES NOT*** scrobble songs you listen to via the normal Music app on your iPhone, it will only scrobble songs listened to via Last.fm's "radio" service. You still have to use a third party app (see above) to scrobble local song listens.

Comment: The riduclous thing is that if you are using the 'remote' app (a controller GUI for a music library) you CAN see the history but if using Music (a controller GUI for a music library) you CANNOT. Both apps made by Apple, both for iOS. Go figure....

Comment: Remote works with a desktop iTunes instance. Music exists solely on the iOS device you're using. The two are not equivalent. Remote is a controller GUI for a remote system. Music is a GUI for managing local media. If Music did everything iTunes did, I'd hate it. Less is more.

Comment: remote, local, so what? it's just the location of a library, the irony being that in this case, everything in the iPhone already exists in the superset that is the iTunes desktop version

Comment: The point remains that Music.app is not merely a controller GUI for a music library. The difference is that Remote.app doesn't output anything, but sends network requests out to another system. Music.app sends requests, sure, but it is also the output medium for the music. You cannot compare these two apps beyond the fact that they both involve music. They serve two entirely different aspects of it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

1. Launch any song in your Music playlist.
2. Touch the name of the song now playing, which will take you to a song-specific screen, which may include album cover art.
3. On that song-specific screen, tap the icon for the bulleted list, just to the right of the skip forward button. This will bring you to a list of upcoming songs, with the one you're currently listening to at the top. Except it's not really the top...
4. Swipe the list down and you will see a list of all the songs you've played previously in reverse chronological order, just above the song you're currently listening to.

Answer (score 1):

Go to music app and top right hand corner says history and it will show played music even from other apps

Comment: Not on the iPhone it doesn't. I did specify this in both the description and tags.

Answer (score 0):

**[QuietScrob](http://quietscrob.droppages.com)** shows up to 50 recently played tracks (via standard Music app)

Comment: AD does tolerate a certain amount of self-promotion, but please be open about it (see this [FAQ entry](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for details).

Answer (score 0):

I was sick to be unable to know what I've listen on music playlist or radio, so I've made an app for that.
I've find it use full for myself, so I've decided to share it:

https://sites.google.com/site/ezmusichistory/home

I hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Now Playing, go to track list, shows now/up next, scroll up, there is the history.

This is on iPhone, Apple Music app.  I am playing an apple curated playlist.